# PHP how to sort output of the array in a 5x5 table?

Tags: php, css, html

I'm very new to PHP.
I am trying to get the game (names) in a 5x5 table with 5 rows and 5 cols.
But i want to generate the table by the number output of games and not a preset html table.
i made it work that it shows the games but not in a table.
Could you please help me and give me a good explaination so i understand too.
Thank's already!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Merijn</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $games = array(
            "battlefield 1",
            "battlefield 2",
            "Out of the Park Baseball 17",
            "Overwatch",
            "Stephen's Sausage Roll",
            "Dark Souls III",
            "Kentucky Route Zero - Act IV NEW",
            "Stardew Valley",
            "Ori and the Blind Forest",
            "XCOM 2",
            "World of Warcraft: Legion",
            "Steins;Gate ",
            "The Witness",
            "Inside",
            "Hex: Shards of Fate",
            "Forza Horizon 3 ",
            "Rise of the Tomb Raider",
            "Total War: WARHAMMER",
            "Chime Sharp",
            "Pony Island",
            "F1 2016",
            "Day of the Tentacle Remastered",
            "Tales from the Borderlands",
            "DOOM",
            "Hearthstone");
            for($i =0; $i <=25; $i++){
                echo '<table rows=5 cols=5>';
                echo "<td>" . $games[$i] . "</td>" .  "<br/>";
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: u need to use table outside the loop, but still this will only print 1 column and multiple rows, and your length should be `$i < 25` because you are starting this from 0

Comment: On a good way to reach your target. @devpro comment shows you some mistakes you need to repair, and then you just need to add opening and closing of <tr> after each 5 of games. You can use $i to check if its modulo division by 5 gives you no reminder and that means its time to start new row.

Comment: @Ranker    Sorry i dont get it. Could you maybe give me a tip or something?

Comment: he is saying you are using <table> inside the loop, which is wrong, @Ranker, now u have 2 solutions, try them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the cleanest but it works :)

```
<?php
$games = array(
            "battlefield 1",
            "battlefield 2",
            "Out of the Park Baseball 17",
            "Overwatch",
            "Stephen's Sausage Roll",
            "Dark Souls III",
            "Kentucky Route Zero - Act IV NEW",
            "Stardew Valley",
            "Ori and the Blind Forest",
            "XCOM 2",
            "World of Warcraft: Legion",
            "Steins;Gate ",
            "The Witness",
            "Inside",
            "Hex: Shards of Fate",
            "Forza Horizon 3 ",
            "Rise of the Tomb Raider",
            "Total War: WARHAMMER",
            "Chime Sharp",
            "Pony Island",
            "F1 2016",
            "Day of the Tentacle Remastered",
            "Tales from the Borderlands",
            "DOOM",
            "Hearthstone");
    $c = 0;
?>
<table>
<tr>
    <?php for ($i=0; $i < count( $games ); $i++) { 
        if( $c == 5 )
        {
          $c = 0;
            ?>
                </tr>
                <tr>

        <?php } echo "<td>".$games[ $i ]."</td>"; $c++;
    } ?>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I'm getting 6 rows, not 5.

Comment: My bad, started the count at 1 instead of 0, fixed and updated

Comment: Could you explain me what this does i dont know the operator $i%5 === 0 for($i =0; $i < 25; $i++){
    if ($i%5 === 0) {
     echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
     echo "<td>" . $games[$i] . "</td>";
    }

Comment: $i%5 === 0 <-- when you divide $i by 5 does it equal zero

Comment: Tank you, was i right it was a operator ? if it is do you maybe know a site where they explain it to me with that operator?

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you must need to use `<table>` outside the loop, than you must need to define 5 columns than you can use your `$games` array as you need:

**Example:**

```
<?php
$games = array(
"battlefield 1",
"battlefield 2",
"Out of the Park Baseball 17",
"Overwatch",
"Stephen's Sausage Roll",
"Dark Souls III",
"Kentucky Route Zero - Act IV NEW",
"Stardew Valley",
"Ori and the Blind Forest",
"XCOM 2",
"World of Warcraft: Legion",
"Steins;Gate ",
"The Witness",
"Inside",
"Hex: Shards of Fate",
"Forza Horizon 3 ",
"Rise of the Tomb Raider",
"Total War: WARHAMMER",
"Chime Sharp",
"Pony Island",
"F1 2016",
"Day of the Tentacle Remastered",
"Tales from the Borderlands",
"DOOM",
"Hearthstone");
?>

<table border="1">
<tr>
<?php
// this will print 5 columns
for ($i=1; $i <= 5 ; $i++) { 
?>
<td><?php echo "Column". $i ?></td> 
<?php
}
?>
</tr> 
<?php
// this will print your games value in 5 rows each
$games = array_chunk($games, 5); // break in chunks
foreach ($games as $key => $value) {
    echo "<tr>"; // starting tr for values
    foreach ($value as $fvalue) { // this will break in 5 rows each.
    ?>
    <td><?=$fvalue?></td>
    <?php           
    }
    echo "</tr>"; // closing tr
}
?>
</table>
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/674967)**

Comment: Gotta love a demo too ;-) Sidenote: In order to get clean HTML, it would be best to add `"\n"` after each element. That way, HTML source won't reveal as one big clump on a single line, which makes it hard to debug if/when HTML source needs to be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
          $games = array(
            "battlefield 1",
            "battlefield 2",
            "Out of the Park Baseball 17",
            "Overwatch",
            "Stephen's Sausage Roll",
            "Dark Souls III",
            "Kentucky Route Zero - Act IV NEW",
            "Stardew Valley",
            "Ori and the Blind Forest",
            "XCOM 2",
            "World of Warcraft: Legion",
            "Steins;Gate ",
            "The Witness",
            "Inside",
            "Hex: Shards of Fate",
            "Forza Horizon 3 ",
            "Rise of the Tomb Raider",
            "Total War: WARHAMMER",
            "Chime Sharp",
            "Pony Island",
            "F1 2016",
            "Day of the Tentacle Remastered",
            "Tales from the Borderlands",
            "DOOM",
            "Hearthstone");


    echo '<table border=1 rows=5 cols=5><tr>';
    for($i =0; $i < 25; $i++){
        if ($i%5 === 0) {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
        }
        echo "<td>" . $games[$i] . "</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr></table>';
```