# How can iterate every 5 results in a table?

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach

I have a foreach that need to be distributed every 5 result per row on a table.

This is my current foreach:

```
<?php 

    $i = 0;
    echo "<tr>";

    foreach($klasifikasi as $result){
       $i++;


       if($i % 5 == 0){
         echo "<td width='20%' align='center'>".$result['klasifikasi']."</td>";
         echo "<td width='20%' align='center'>".$result['klasifikasi']."png</td>"; }

    };
    echo "</tr>";
?>
```

It doesn't stop every 5 result and doesn't create new row.

This is what I'm looking for:

```
---------------------------------------------------
A1      |  A2      |   A3      |  A4      |  A5
---------------------------------------------------
A1.png  |  A2.png  |   A3.png  |  A4.png  |  A5.png
---------------------------------------------------
/*this row should be empty for some spacing*/
---------------------------------------------------
.../*skipped till the last row*/
---------------------------------------------------
A21     |  A22      |     A23     |    A24
---------------------------------------------------
A21.png |  A22.png  |     A23.png |    A24.png
---------------------------------------------------
```

My current result from the iteration is 24 data. It may become more or less

**note:**

if possible, every columns that are **not** empty should have widht of 20%

Comment: Have a look at this post from yesterday - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510272/php-how-to-sort-output-of-the-array-in-a-5x5-table/40510543#40510543

Comment: You're not creating rows in your `foreach`loop, you're creating cells.

Comment: are there any 'foreach' solution?. Not 'for'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to your problem:

```
    $i = 1;
    $html = "<table border='1'>";

    $row1 = '<tr>';
    $row2 = '<tr>';
    foreach($klasifikasi as $result){
        $row1 .= "<td width='20%' align='center'>".$result['klasifikasi']."</td>";
        $row2 .= "<td width='20%' align='center'>".$result['klasifikasi']."png</td>";

        if($i > 0 && $i % 5 === 0){
            $row1 .= '</tr>';
            $row2 .= '</tr>';
            $html .= $row1.$row2;
            $html .= '<tr><td colspan="5"></td></tr>;

            $row1 = '<tr>';
            $row2 = '<tr>';
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if($i > 0 && $i % 5 !== 1) {
        $html .= $row1.$row2;
    }
    $html .= '</table>';
    echo $html;
```

Comment: Add it in the end

Comment: Umm.. my foreach should return 24 results. But the code only print 20 results.

Comment: @Vahn can you `print_r($klasifikasi)`

Comment: I just fixed one of the if statements and now it is ok

Comment: @krasipenkov Thank you so much. just one minor problem. How can I add one empty row (forspacing purpose) after the 'png' row?

Comment: @krasipenkov It's perfect. Thank you soooo much

Answer (score 0):

Use nested loops. The outer loop should iterate by 5, and the inner loop gets the 5 items within that group.

```
$len = count($klasifikasi);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i += 5) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j = $i; $j < $i+5; $j++) {
        if ($j < $len) {
            echo "<td>{$row['klasifikasi']}</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j = $i; $j < $i+5; $j++) {
        if ($j < $len) {
            echo "<td>{$row['klasifikasi']}.png</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But, I have to use foreach. not for. I'm using CodeIgniter

Comment: I've never used CodeIgniter. Why does it force you to use `foreach`?